# How to Get Loop to move for the next range?

Tags: vba, until-loop

I'd like to get the following code running for the same range but for different rows, until there is no more data in the rows.

So I'd like to get VBA to copy ("P7,T7"), paste it at ("A5")
copy ("B2") and paste it at ("X7") - and so on... until there is no more data in the row.

```
Range("P6,T6").Select 

Range("T6").Activate 

Selection.Copy 

Range("A5").Select 

ActiveSheet.Paste 

Range("B2").Select 

Application.CutCopyMode = False 

Selection.Copy 

Range("X6").Select 

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ 

    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: First, I would suggest simplifying your code. To copy values you don't actually need to use `Select`, `Copy` or `Paste`. You can just do `Destination.Value = Source.Value` Like `Range("A5").Value = Range("P7").Value`

Comment: You can separate the range addresses into Row & Column, for example `Range("A5")` is the same as `Cells(5, 1)` which is the same as `Range("A" & 5)`. Then you can swap out `5` for a variable like `x` and you can create a loop like `For x = 2 To 10`. I suggest reading more about [For Loops](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html). And checking out the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement)